# How to display ad in uitableview admob swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, tableview

I am very new to admob nativeads and I checked every tutorial
online on how to add ads in tableview, but I did not find any luck
This is the code I have so far in my cellforrowat function:

```
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NativeAdTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! NativeAdTableViewCell
        
        print("ad = \(ad == nil)")
        cell.adTitle.text = ad?.headline
        cell.adSubtitle.text = ad?.body
        cell.img.image = ad?.icon?.image
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        return cell
```

Other code:

```
func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {
    nativeAd.delegate = self
    ad = nativeAd
}
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add an empty element in your tableView dataSource array when receive your add like below:

```
func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd {
   nativeAd.delegate = self
   self.yourDataSource.insert("", at: 0) // add empty element in where you show your ads
   ad = nativeAd
   yourTableView.reloadData() 
}
```

After that  your tableViewCell look like :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let data = self.yourDataSource[indexPath.row]as? [String]
    if data == nil {
        
        let nativeAd = self.ad //Your native ads object
        nativeAd.rootViewController = self
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nativecell", for: indexPath)as! nativecell // nativecell is your native ad cell
        let adView = cell.adview
        adView!.nativeAd = nativeAd
        cell.headline.text = nativeAd.headline
        cell.icon.image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        cell.body.text = nativeAd.body
        cell.action.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.action.setTitle(nativeAd.callToAction, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        return cell
        
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "regularCell", for: indexPath)as! regularCell
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got it to work!

Comment: Wait I have a quick question, the information of ad is displayed, but the ad is unclickable, I copied your code, why is that?

Comment: make sure all your component is within GADNativeUnifiedAdView in your tableViewCell

Comment: Does anyone have an obj C version for this?