# Handling Events On Admob UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, admob

fairly new to Admob. I've been trying to implement AdMob native ads on UICollectionView but I've had little to no luck. I've been able to load and show the ad in a cell but events are not registered e.g views or clicks with the GADNativeAdDelegate. This is the code so far:

```swift
// In main view controller
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "exampleCell", for: indexPath) as! exampleCell
 let myItem = myItemList[indexPath.item]
         if myItem is GADNativeAd {
        let nAd = myItems as! GADNativeAd
        let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UnifiedNativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first
        let nativeAdView = nibView as! GADNativeAdView
        
        // Prepare ad content
        let nativeAd = nAd
        
        // Add content to native view
        (nativeAdView.headlineView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.headline
          nativeAdView.mediaView?.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        
        (nativeAdView.bodyView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.body
        nativeAdView.bodyView?.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil
        
        (nativeAdView.iconView as? UIImageView)?.image = nativeAd.icon?.image
          nativeAdView.iconView?.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil
        
        (nativeAdView.advertiserView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.advertiser
          nativeAdView.advertiserView?.isHidden = nativeAd.advertiser == nil
        
        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        nativeAdView.nativeAd?.delegate = self
        nativeAdView.nativeAd?.rootViewController = self
        cell.addSubview(nativeAdView)

        return cell
     }
}
```

My cell is a basic UICollectionViewCell that is empty as follows:

```swift
class exampleCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

}
```

I've had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748200/how-to-display-ad-in-uitableview-admob-swift) but it doesn't seem to be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

In cellForItemAt delegate
try this
// Remove previous GADBannerView from the content view before adding a new one.

```
for subview in reusableAdCell.contentView.subviews {
      
subview.removeFromSuperview()
  
}
```